# Showing that $H_{\text{loc}}^2(\mathbb{R}^2) \subset C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I want to show that $H_{\text{loc}}^2(\mathbb{R}^2) \subset C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$

$C^0$ is the space of continuous functions, and $H_{\text{loc}}^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ the set of distributions $u\in D'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for which $\phi u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for all test-functions $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I found the right definition. Im editing the post now.

Comment: My guess at what the definition of $H^2_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$ should be is the functions $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ such that for each $x \in \Omega$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \subseteq \Omega$ of $x$ such that $f|_U \in H^2(U)$. I.e. basically mimicking the definition of $L^2_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @kahen I don't think that's correct. At least, it's not any of the equivalent definitions given in Folland.

Comment: Thanks. I found one. Ill edit the post and see if you agree

Comment: Look up a proof of the Sobolev embedding theorem.

Comment: I found this Sobolev-theorem: If $m\geq 0$ integer and $s>m+n/2$ then $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C^m_{L^{\infty}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So we have $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset C^0_{L^{\infty}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. How is this helping us?

Comment: Continuity is a local property. If $\phi u$ is continuous for all test functions $\phi$, then so it  $u$.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting a CW to not leave the question unanswered.

1. Let $u\in H^2_{\rm loc}$. It suffices to prove that $u$ is continuous on $B_r=\{x:|x|<r\}$ for every $r$.
2. There is a test function $\phi$ such that $\phi=1$ on $B_r$
3. Since $\phi u\in H^2$, the Sobolev embedding implies that $\phi u$ is continuous. Therefore $u$ is continuous on $B_r=\{x:|x|<r\}$.